# Cross browser Custom formatted html date control

Tags: html, css, datepicker, webkit, custom-datetimepicker

i need some help to modify a html date control (custom date formatted)..
I am stuck with cross browser compatibility..
In Chrome , it works fine, but safari could not display the value..
I am not so good in cross browser compatibility..
following is the link to describe the issue...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/)

```
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance..Someone could provide solution..

Comment: It looks like you're setting the `data-date` but not the `value` when it updates.

Comment: Value is being set , as you can see in chorme browser...

Comment: So then perhaps I'm confused on the issue. Does the value get set in Safari?

Comment: first of all..input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator.. this indicator is not visible in safari browser . and also value is not being show.. if you highlight the field in safari, value will be shown or just change the color from white to black, it will be shown